Question on "The State of Theology", Arian heresy, and salvation
The Ligonier Ministries' 2022 "State of Theology" contains some interesting things.  One such thing is that over half of those surveyed agreed (some strongly) with the following statement:

Jesus is the first and greatest being created by God.

What's even more interesting to me is that the percentage agreeing with this statement across all denominations surveyed goes up as their frequency of church attendance goes up.  Links to The State of Theology Data Explorer on the above question (#6):

All respondents: 40% strongly agree, 15% somewhat agree, 13% not sure
Beliefs: Evangelicals: 70% strongly agree, 3% somewhat agree, 5% not sure

Excerpt from an article that focuses the data on evangelicals: The State of Theology: What Evangelicals Believe in 2022:

Almost three out of four (73 percent) agree with the claim that Jesus is the “first and greatest being created by God.”

Hypothesizing a bit on this: let's assume these numbers accurately represent the state of theology in the U.S. (I know they might not).  Are over half of the Christians in the U.S. anathema for believing this?  Will they not attain to salvation?
I'm looking for a Biblical answer to this question (all denominations and translations welcome).

I added a link to the data explorer and one article that uses that data.

The survey reveals that only half of the 3,011 persons surveyed believed that God is perfect, only half believed in the Trinity, half agreed that 'God learns and adapts' and about half do not firmly believe that Jesus rose from the dead. I am just wondering by what means the surveyors gathered such persons together.

@GratefulDisciple That would explain it if the study only involved evangelicals...but it doesn't.

@Aleph-Gimel Never mind.  I deleted my comment.  I think the question is easily misunderstood.  They remember the teaching "firstborn of all creation" (Col 1:15) and "creation is by him through him and for him" (Col 1:16, John 1:3, 1 Cor 8:6) and thought how the incarnation "begins" in a manger at Betlehem (although Jesus as Word preexisted), so thought the survey question refers to that teaching.

@GratefulDisciple Of course, that makes sense that they remember col 1:15 and others...but my question is what are the implications of that.  Are they saved?  Of course, the business of saving isn't up to us (and thankfully so).  But I'm wondering if this could be answered Biblically.

@Aleph-Gimel Let me know whether I addressed your question in my answer.  Please provide feedback there.

@GratefulDisciple I appreciate your answer and I did leave some feedback there - not sure if you saw that?

@Aleph-Gimel Provided an edit for my answer.

@GratefulDisciple Well done - upvoted.

@GratefulDisciple Yes the problem is that 'Prototokos' should not be translated 'firstborn'. The concept is made clear by Luke's use of the word 'tokos' to convey 'usury'. Christ is the 'first token' of a new creation. The first instalment of an investment. The concept is being mis-taught.

Culpability of one's defective theology with regards to salvation
I think question #6 is easily misunderstood. Many church goers probably remember their pastors teaching how Jesus is the "firstborn of all creation" (Col 1:15), how "creation is by him through him and for him" (Col 1:16, John 1:3, 1 Cor 8:6) and how the incarnation "began" in a manger at Betlehem (although Jesus as Word pre-existed), so they may have thought that the survey question #6 refers to the teaching above, to which they mistakenly answer "I agree".
Holding defective theology because of ignorance doesn't ruin one's salvation.  I don't think this findings is enough to make them "Arian" especially considering

They are not seminary educated pastors nor are they professional theologians
They answer the other theological question correctly (#2, There is one true God in three persons: God the Father, God the Son, and God the Holy Spirit) correctly.

In a class final exam, the teacher can presume the students to have learned the material, and can pass/fail a student based on wrong cognitive statement.  But salvation is a matter of our heart's alignment with God's heart who IS Perfect Love (cf Great Commandment plus 1 John 4:7-12), helped by correct understanding of God of course, which is why good churches have Sunday school programs for children and adults alike.  But going to heaven is not about passing a cognitively-laden test as if before passing to heaven we have to sit down in a classroom being given a sheet full of catechism questions to which we have to have 90% correct.  If the adult respondents fail to answer question #6, I suggest it's more due to lacking exposure to good lay theological education in the local churches than an indicator of one's salvation, as God will judge individual's heart, as well as adding an additional criteria for pastors (1 Cor 3:15).
But if the respondents are seminary-trained pastors and theologians who usually have taken a systematic theology course at a Trinitarian seminary (we are presuming this question to deal only with mainstream Trinitarian groups), then YES, if they hold to this position with full conviction and understanding, they are more at risk for losing their salvation because of this false doctrinal belief, which is linked directly to their false understanding of Jesus, which in turn can detrimentally affect their heart's condition before God.  Still, it remains for God to judge whether this person goes to heaven.  A lot of other factors are in play here, so this "false answer" by pastors / theologians still shouldn't be considered as God's automatic veto, disregarding all other factors such as the quality of one's heart when measured by perfect love.
Anathema and the correct audience
By anathema I think you meant the "formal excommunication by a church", which implies that since they are no longer in the Ark of Noah they will lose their salvation.  In the Arian controversy context, this refers to the last section of the Nicene Creed (325):

But as for those who say, There was when He was not, and, before being born He was not, and that He came into existence out of nothing, or who assert that the Son of God is from a different hypostasis or substance, or is created, or is subject to alteration or change – these the Catholic Church anathemizes.

See also the discussion about anathema in chapter 8 of Philip Schaff's often cited book, The Creeds of Christendom: with a History and Critical Notes ((1877).
The potential for pastors and theologians holding false theology to misinform others is the background for the anathemizing language found in Scriptures as well as in the canons of church councils from 4th century to even the 16th century council of Trent.  Pronouncing anathema is serious language ([Insert a segment from Truth Unites YouTube where Gavin explained what anathema meant).  So the 2 Biblical occurrences in @DanFefferman's answer are for serious matters: correct gospel, and about having love for the Lord.
Why did the council fathers use the language of anathema for those holding the Arian view?  I suggest that the main audience was those theologically educated leaders in the church who were at serious risk to teach a wrong understanding of Jesus, which in turn could affect one's salvation among the hundreds-of-thousand of souls divided among flocks, each under a bishop's charge whose main responsibility was to teach.  Closer to our time, I suggest that the main audience of the 16th century Council of Trent was also church leaders in the Reformation era whose salvation related teachings (like sola fide) pose a serious risk to lead the (now in the  millions) souls to spiritual harm.
Your Q applies for lay individual, not theologically educated church leader, so I suggest this anathema language doesn't apply to those who answered #6 incorrectly.  Yes, I would need to substantiate more of that context for anathema, but I hope just by framing it this way is reasonable enough.
Better indicators for one's salvation and positive influence from one's church-going pattern
But the questions below are a lot better indicator of their salvation because they pointed to their believing sola gratia and sola christus, the Biblical teaching for how salvation works.  These questions are also a much better indicator of what Jesus means to them personally and functionally.  Not surprisingly, Evangelicals "pass" with flying colors:

#2 (97%): There is one true God in three persons: God the Father, God the Son, and God the Holy Spirit.
#5 (99%): Biblical accounts of the physical (bodily) resurrection of Jesus are completely accurate. This event actually occurred.
#14 (93%): God counts a person as righteous not because of one’s works but only because of one’s faith in Jesus Christ.
#21 (98%): There will be a time when Jesus Christ returns to judge all the people who have lived.
#33 (99%): It is very important for me personally to encourage non-Christians to trust Jesus Christ as their Savior.
#34 (99%): Jesus Christ’s death on the cross is the only sacrifice that could remove the penalty of my sin.
#35 (99%): Only those who trust in Jesus Christ alone as their Savior receive God’s free gift of eternal salvation.

If we now include everyone (non-Evangelicals included) but filter by Attendance (at least once a week), here's the result compared to the general population:

#2 (94% vs. 70%): There is one true God in three persons: God the Father, God the Son, and God the Holy Spirit.
#5 (92% vs. 66%): Biblical accounts of the physical (bodily) resurrection of Jesus are completely accurate. This event actually occurred.
#6 (70% vs. 55%): Jesus is the first and greatest being created by God.
#14 (78% vs. 57%): God counts a person as righteous not because of one’s works but only because of one’s faith in Jesus Christ.
#21 (90% vs. 64%): There will be a time when Jesus Christ returns to judge all the people who have lived.
#33 (86% vs. 56%): It is very important for me personally to encourage non-Christians to trust Jesus Christ as their Savior.
#34 (89% vs. 64%): Jesus Christ’s death on the cross is the only sacrifice that could remove the penalty of my sin.
#35 (85% vs. 60%): Only those who trust in Jesus Christ alone as their Savior receive God’s free gift of eternal salvation.

The net effect of church attendance is positive for questions that pertain more closely to salvation than to theology.  Question #14 is not as high as other indicators because Catholics don't agree with it.  Evangelical pastors looking at this data have their homework cut out for them to include theology lessons in their sermons.
But the result for question #7 (Jesus was a great teacher, but he was not God) is especially troubling, much more troubling than #6, because only God can save you.  Only 54% who choose Beliefs:Evangelicals got it right, while those who attended church at least once a week got only 50% vs. 36% for general population.  Maybe it's a little comforting that when the filter is both Beliefs:Evangelicals and Affiliation:Evangelical, the correct percentage improves to 71%, and when they are married and attend at least weekly it becomes 78%.

I also noticed number 7 there.  But also look again at number 2.  Out of all surveyed only 54% strongly agreed.  That leaves 46% that only somewhat agree, don't know, somewhat disagree, or strongly disagree.  I agree with you that this doesn't result in condemnation.  But I think others may not agree with that.

Thankfully, the Lord knows those who are His so we don't have to assign salvation or condemnation.

In other words, to borrow from Obi Wan Kenobi,  when one considers Col 1:15, #6 could be said to be true "from a certain point of view".

@MikeBorden Absolutely! I'm grateful the judging isn't left up to us :)  The Bible does give evidence of the parameters that will be used for assigning salvation, however.  And there's not one verse I can think of that says eternal damnation belongs to those who think Jesus is created.

@Aleph-Gimel Will edit it later today about interpreting anathema, as is often associated with council texts.

@Aleph-Gimel Yup.  Unless you believe that I am He, You will die in your sins.

@MikeBorden I respect your interpretation and always enjoy reading what you write here.  With that being said, you have to read quite a bit into that verse to read it as, "those who believe Jesus is created are without salvation".  This is, of course, just my opinion.

@Aleph-Gimel I think it's more a matter of whether the Son is believed to have been created.  Jesus, the Word made flesh, has an obvious starting point.  Not so the Logos.  John 8:12-30 is important contextual info, IMHO.

@MikeBorden Appreciate that - so you don't believe that the Son was always named Jesus?  Maybe I should rephrase my point like this: reading John 8:24 as, "those who believe the Son is generated/originated/formed/brought forth/made (insert other synonym here) are without salvation" is a stressed reading of that verse, in my opinion.

@Aleph-Gimel I think the Son is generated/originated/formed/brought forth/made (insert other synonym here).  But eternally so.   Eternally begotten.  There never was no Son.  Just as there never was no Logos, the rational mind of God.

@MikeBorden Right on, so only the Father is without cause and unoriginated in your view?

@Aleph-Gimel The way I understand how Jesus is called the "Son of God" (from Chalcedonian Trinitarian perspective) is that Jesus is BOTH the fleshy manifestation of the eternally generated Word (thus "Son" because of this eternal generation within the God-head, nothing to do with creation) AND "son of God" in the human sense, just as David and us and Adam are all "sons & daughters of God" who share the latter 2 sonship in the list of 4 meanings I cited in my other answer.

@Aleph-Gimel In Jesus's time, the people thought Jesus was referring to himself as the "son of God" in the second sense, but when Jesus claimed He was more than that ("Before Abraham I was", etc.) Jesus indicated that He is on the same level of God.  So later theologians work out this relationship in Chalcedonian Trinitarian terms, consistent with the testimony of the NT writers who we believe are faithful to the true representation Jesus made of himself to the apostles.

@GratefulDisciple For sure, it's easy to get caught up in words and even squabble about them.  I think concept behind the use of the word, "created/make" is out of nothing (ex nihilo).  The Bible certainly makes it seem like the concept of "ad intra" (from within) is more along the lines of the begetting of the Son.  But if someone wants to use "create" over "beget" I don't mind.  There are even (minority) translations that have Eve say she made/produced/created a man in Genesis 4:1 even though it was an act of begetting.

@GratefulDisciple Interesting wording of John 8:58 that you've placed there...which translation is that, if you don't mind my asking?

@Aleph-Gimel YLT renders John 8:58 as "Before Abraham's coming, I am".  God is uncaused.  Some would say self-existent.  Care in terminology is required.  Father is who God is.  Logos/Son is God's rational mind.  Holy Spirit is God's operating power.  Son and H.S. have Father as "generative source" but, as Father has never been without mind and power, I am not certain they can rightly be called created.  I favor Eternally Begotten in trying to express such things.


Come now, and let us reason together, saith the LORD: though your sins be as scarlet, they shall be as white as snow; though they be red like crimson, they shall be as wool. - Isaiah 1:18

Here is the invitation.  With what God has immutably spoken, inerrantly inspired, and sovereignly protected down through these long ages as the given assumptions, the logical data, let us reason out together with Him those things concerning sin, righteousness, and judgement.

Whom shall he teach knowledge? and whom shall he make to understand doctrine? them that are weaned from the milk, and drawn from the breasts. For precept must be upon precept, precept upon precept; line upon line, line upon line; here a little, and there a little: For with stammering lips and another tongue will he speak to this people. To whom he said, This is the rest wherewith ye may cause the weary to rest; and this is the refreshing: yet they would not hear. But the word of the LORD was unto them precept upon precept, precept upon precept; line upon line, line upon line; here a little, and there a little; that they might go, and fall backward, and be broken, and snared, and taken. - Isaiah 28:9-13

Additionally, these things are given to us precept upon precept, line upon line, here a little and there a little.  The stated purpose of this method is much like the stated purpose of Jesus' parables:  That those without ears will not hear.  If the foundational precepts and lines are not heard (believed) and built upon there can be no forward movement in reason.
"In the beginning God...".  At some point there was simply God.  No time, no matter, perhaps no space.  There are some religions which teach an eternal nature of matter but there is much Scripture pointing to God alone being everlasting (from eternity to eternity) and Creator of everything else.

In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. - John 1:1

This Word, this Logos, is not merely an utterance (that would be lego or laleo, with synonyms epo or kaleo) and not merely the thought behind the utterance, but it is the intelligence underlying the thought.  It is God's rational mind and His expression thereof.
This is what was made flesh to dwell among us (John 1:14); the Logos, the rational, intelligent mind of God.  Jesus Christ is God's mind expressed in flesh.  To suppose that this Logos was God's first creation is to suppose that prior to this first creation God had no rational mind.
If this most basic precept of the eternal Logos of the eternal God is not the foundation for the next precept and line then whatever is built will not stand when the storm comes, it cannot survive the coming fire of the coming Day.
Stating whether any particular person is or is not anathema is way above the pay grade of most (all?).  However, believing that the Logos of God had a point of creation, a starting point, is a very foundational wrong turn of reason.  It is the rejection of a precept and cannot be corrected by any additional reasoning.  One must go back to the point of departure and assimilate precept and line as God has given it.

I am one that bear witness of myself, and the Father that sent me beareth witness of me. Then said they unto him, Where is thy Father? Jesus answered, Ye neither know me, nor my Father: if ye had known me, ye should have known my Father also. These words spake Jesus in the treasury, as he taught in the temple: and no man laid hands on him; for his hour was not yet come. Then said Jesus again unto them, I go my way, and ye shall seek me, and shall die in your sins: whither I go, ye cannot come. Then said the Jews, Will he kill himself? because he saith, Whither I go, ye cannot come. And he said unto them, Ye are from beneath; I am from above: ye are of this world; I am not of this world. I said therefore unto you, that ye shall die in your sins: for if ye believe not that I am (he), ye shall die in your sins. Then said they unto him, Who art thou? And Jesus saith unto them, Even the same that I said unto you from the beginning. - John 8:18-25

If you believe not that I am ...who or what?  Whether or not we die in our sins depends upon the answer to that question.  It is a very biblical teaching.

A wrong understanding of who Jesus, the Christ, really is, leads to a wrong understanding of what God, in Jesus, has done to save us from our sins. The Son of God was begotten - not created - and no created angel could ever be the Son of God. As you rightly point out, if people do not believe that Jesus, the Christ, the Son of God, is who he says he is, we are lost.

Up-voted +1. Wise words indeed. It is the rejection of a precept and cannot be corrected by any additional reasoning. One must go back to the point of departure and assimilate precept and line as God has given it. Very true, Brother Michael. If one errs right at the beginning, progress will be deviant, Repentance requires that we go back to the beginning and start again.

"Stating whether any particular person is or is not anathema is way above the pay grade of most (all?)" - 100% agree with you there, my friend.  However, "To suppose that this Logos was God's first creation is to suppose that prior to this first creation God had no rational mind." doesn't necessarily follow.  If I had the power to beget the reason within me as another person, that doesn't mean that I didn't have reason before the begetting.  I think this is the crux of the Arian controversy.  Did the Son come from within God or did he come from something external like "nothingness".

"If you believe not that I am ...who or what?" -  John 20:31 - the Christ/Messiah.  Of course, people differ in their belief about who the Messiah is.  Even within trinitarian belief there are differences between the east and west.  Either the holy spirit proceeds from the Son or it doesn't (filioque).  Which side is right?  Does it matter?  Does one preach a different Jesus than the other?  I suppose my point is that there's enough confusion on the topic that you could study it for your entire life and miss the point.  God won't hold you accountable for that, in my opinion.

@Aleph-Gimel I would respond that prior to God's creation activity (assuming He created literally everything) there was nothing that was external to God including Logos.  The supposition of some is that the Son did not exist and then He did exist by an act of creation.  However, if the Son is Logos then He has always been internal to God and has always existed.  Begetting then is a term used to try to express how God generates or sources or produces His own mind rather than bringing it into existence.

@MikeBorden Yes exactly, how could "nothingness" exist if it hadn't been created yet.  I suppose we know more about our universe now than in Arius' day lol.  I guess I lean more towards the early church logos christology than the eternal generation but that's getting into personal views.  At the end of the day (in my opinion but I feel it can be backed up by scripture), what you believe is important...but what you DO is even more so - James 2:19

@Aleph-Gimel The demons tremble because they have correct knowledge of God and yet no action based upon that.  If you will, they have "faith without works" in the highest degree.  What we DO is important in that it demonstrates (justifies) our faith but it is never the DOING that saves.  This is the careful tension between James here and Paul in Romans 4.  Abraham justified by works and Abraham justified by faith.  It is by Abraham's action that his faith was made perfect.

@Aleph-Gimel I would say works without faith is vanity (without faith it is impossible to please God) and then ask how accurate the faith has to be.  As James is careful to point out, "And the scripture was fulfilled (played out) which saith, Abraham believed God, and it was imputed unto him for righteousness".  Righteousness was credited to him because of a belief in God's promise in Gen. 15 which didn't even play itself out in Abraham's deeds until chapter 22.  Isaac wasn't even born yet when the faith in question justified Abraham.  The question really is:  What takes away sin?

@Aleph-Gimel What is the work of God so that faith may come?  Believe on the one that He has sent.  Receive Him (John 1:12).  Then comes the indwelling Spirit producing the fruit of faith (among other things), which faith generates works.  We believe on Him and then live by His faith born in us.  Now even the works that we do are to His glory and not ours.  It is God who works in us to will and to do of His good pleasure.  Works that demonstrate a faith which is given to us and nothing by which we can boast before God (Rom 4:1-5). What we believe/receive is crucial for access to this grace.

@MikeBorden I'm definitely in agreement with that, my friend.  Faith has to come first.   And, yes, works without faith is in vain.  I'm not of the mentality that you can believe whatever you want about Jesús as long as you do good.  What you believe is absolutely important but, again, what you DO about it is more so.  Here's an example: two Christians are on different sides of families of beliefs.  For arguments sake, one is Catholic and the other is Seventh Day Adventist.  They both believe in Jesus although their christologies are different.  One lives their life observing...

Jesus' words and the other doesn’t.  Which DID the will of God?  Matthew 7:21 places emphasis on doing over believing.  Think also of the parable of the good Samaritan.  There are a plethora of other verses that would apply here as well, and, as we both agree God is the ultimate judge so I won't formally say who will be saved or not.

@Aleph-Gimel Absolutely!  Doing the will of God is crucial.  How is that accomplished?  It is God working in us to will and to do His good pleasure.  Hence many will prophesy, cast out demons, and do miracles in His name only to discover that He never knew them.  The question ultimately is, Must one receive anything specific about the Lord Jesus in order to be born again; for His Spirit to indwell one and enable the works of genuine faith or is merely claiming His name good enough?  Is the one who has received the Son as God and the one who has received the Son as a creation on equal footing?

@MikeBorden And we've gone full circle back to my question lol.  I think the answer to that is generally yes with some exceptions and an explanation.  You seem to think the answer is no?  I also think that if/when we attain salvation we'll be surprised about who else did or didn't.

@Aleph-Gimel 1John says we can know that we have eternal life.  I held the if/when position up until I was actually born-again.

@MikeBorden Sure thing, no problem there,  my friend.  But even if you know your own salvation is secure...you could still be surprised at who else does or doesn't attain to it.

@Aleph-Gimel I try not to make any such determination but I will certainly be surprised if folks who believe Jesus was nothing other than a mortal man attain to it, for example.  Whatever is, is.  He cannot be both God and non-God.

@MikeBorden Isn't that what the hypostatic union entails?

@Aleph-Gimel  Not what I mean.  Some believe Jesus was both God and man.  Some believe Jesus was only man.  Some believe Jesus was something less than God (angel?) and man.  Not sure if anyone believes Jesus was only God and not man.  These cannot all be true:  Whatever Jesus is, He is.  Who attains salvation through untruth?  Granted, no one understands everything at the outset (John 5:13, 9:25, etc.) but if the saved are indwelt and guided into all truth we shouldn't expect conclusions that exclude one another, I think.

@MikeBorden Maybe you just mean to say that as to his nature, Jesus can be and is both God and not God (divine versus created nature)?  But as to his identity he is only God?  At any rate - I agree with you when you say that he can't be both God and not God.  It just seems to me that the doctrine of the hypostatic union contradicts that view.

@Aleph-Gimel  That's not really what I meant by my poorly worded comment, though.  I believe Jesus was and is both fully Divine and fully human.  What I mean is that he cannot be both that and not that.

@MikeBorden - Noted.  That makes more sense.

The OP asks "Are over half of the Christians in the U.S. anathema for believing (that Jesus Christ is the first creation of God.") To start, as @Grateful Diciple mentions, we should consider that an answer given to a pollster is not a formal theological declaration. Historically the teachers of the Arian heresy were not punished for informal statements but only for being a notorious teacher of the heresy or refusing to affirm the Nicene Creed and its successors.
The OP also says it is looking of a "biblical answer." The Bible uses the term "anathema" rarely. Specific instances include:
Galatians 1:8

But even if we or an angel from heaven should proclaim to you a gospel
contrary to what we proclaimed to you, let that one be accursed!

Here, Paul refers to those who teach that one must become an observant Jew in order be a true Christian.
1 Corinthians 16:22a

Let anyone be accursed who has no love for the Lord.

There are other cases where Paul recommends excommunication, but the specific word "anathema" (under a curse) is very rare indeed.
Conclusion: as far as the Bible goes, the Arian heresy is not specified as being worthy of the curse. One has to interpret the Bible along the lines of the Ecumenical Councils in order in to reach the conclusion a person is anathema for believing Jesus to be a "creation" of God. In any case, one's eternal damnation is not determined by responding in ignorance to a theological poll.

Right so purely Biblically speaking, there's no basis for saying that one is accursed for believing that Jesus is created. You have to get into councils to arrive at that viewpoint.

Just to add that the anathema Paul warned of re. a different gospel, was not restricted to tacking on Judaic practices. Verse 16 has Paul saying Christ was revealed in him that he could preach Christ to the Gentiles. Any gospel message that does not reveal just who this Jesus Christ truly is, becomes a false gospel, a distortion. Even though Arius was not to be born for many years, so Arianism did not yet exist, Paul's anathema surely includes preaching Christ as a creature as no created man could atone for sin? If no atonement, then no gospel. But +1.

I respectfully disagree regarding what Paul refers to in Galatians. The reference there is clearly the Judaizing heresy not Arianism. He may well have agreed with the orthodox position when the issue was debated centuries later, but in his writings the issue does not come up.
